# How to find out who ruins KEY_TYPED event?

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, awt, keyevent

I have a Java application with many text fields where i can enter for example `é` by pressing `` ` `` and then `e`. This is the behaviour as known from many applications.

Now after a specific user operation (starting a specific module of the application) all text fields in the application won't be able to type `é`.

Here is what I did:

Does it happen on Windows or Linux? Only Windows.

Does it happen with a specific JVM? AFAIS not - using 6-32/64 and 7-32/64 I'm able to reproduce the problem.

Does it happen with a specific code base of the application? Yes, but it might be useful information that I'm unable to reproduce the problem from within Eclipse. Just the packaged application has the problem.

What events occur?

Before starting the module:

```
*!*!* dispatching: java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=129,keyText=Akut (Dead),keyChar='┤',keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=221,primaryLevelUnicode=180,scancode=13,extendedKeyCode=0x81] on mainFrame
*!*!* dispatching: java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_RELEASED,keyCode=129,keyText=Akut (Dead),keyChar='┤',keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=221,primaryLevelUnicode=180,scancode=13,extendedKeyCode=0x81] on mainFrame
*!*!* dispatching: java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=69,keyText=E,keyChar='e',keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=69,primaryLevelUnicode=101,scancode=18,extendedKeyCode=0x45] on mainFrame
*!*!* dispatching: java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_TYPED,keyCode=0,keyText=Unbekannt keyCode: 0x0,keyChar='Ú',keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_UNKNOWN,rawCode=0,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=0,extendedKeyCode=0x0] on mainFrame
*!*!* dispatching: java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_RELEASED,keyCode=69,keyText=E,keyChar='e',keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=69,primaryLevelUnicode=101,scancode=18,extendedKeyCode=0x45] on mainFrame
```

After starting the module:

```
*!*!* dispatching: java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=129,keyText=Akut (Dead),keyChar='┤',keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=221,primaryLevelUnicode=180,scancode=13,extendedKeyCode=0x81] on mainFrame
*!*!* dispatching: java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_RELEASED,keyCode=129,keyText=Akut (Dead),keyChar='┤',keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=221,primaryLevelUnicode=180,scancode=13,extendedKeyCode=0x81] on mainFrame
*!*!* dispatching: java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=69,keyText=E,keyChar='e',keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=69,primaryLevelUnicode=101,scancode=18,extendedKeyCode=0x45] on mainFrame
*!*!* dispatching: java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_TYPED,keyCode=0,keyText=Unbekannt keyCode: 0x0,keyChar='e',keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_UNKNOWN,rawCode=0,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=0,extendedKeyCode=0x0] on mainFrame
*!*!* dispatching: java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_RELEASED,keyCode=69,keyText=E,keyChar='e',keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=69,primaryLevelUnicode=101,scancode=18,extendedKeyCode=0x45] on mainFrame
```

As you see in the output, encoding is obvious a point where I have little knowledge. So encoding might be a problem even though I don't understand where to set it and why the problem would only occur after a specific point in time. So personally I don't think encoding is the reason. I tried using `-Dfile.encoding=Cp1252` `-Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-15` but the problem still exists on Windows outside of Eclipse and doesn't occur on Linux or inside Eclipse.

So what am I expecting? I need somebody who can tell what I should look for to find the reason for this strange problem. Any documentation I found about KeyEvents is too much for beginners, I need the documentation for the point where I am now. Who does construct the `KEY_TYPED` events? Or who is responsible for manipulating the wrong event?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found the cause of the problem by simply remote debugging and stepping threw all steps the events were passed. It's annoying because there is no solution how to analyse the next problem of that sort.

The problem in my case was that deep inside the malicious module a class called `KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(..)` and `KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventPostProcessor(..)` to redirect events to the objects of it to react to KeyEvents even if they occurred in child components.

The problem is that this dispatcher and processor called `e.consume()` which might influence the creation of the `KEY_TYPED` event. Fact is that when removing the consuming of the event, everything works.

Inside the eclipse the thing didn't happen because some classes were not on the classpath and therefore after the lookup failed the malicious class wasn't called at that point. Frustrating.

Even though I found the solution, it would be interesting which steps I could do to debug something like that? Or is there any documentation of how events are created low level?